# Add background image to <ol> numbers

Tags: css

I can't figure out an elegant way to accomplish the following using CSS:

[image: screenshot]

I need the numbers of the ordered list to have the teal bubble-looking background. I have this image (which includes the white stroke):

[image: bubble]

But I can't figure out how to put it behind each of the numbers using CSS. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
    color: white;
}
ol li {

    background-image: url('nswCH.png');
    background-position: -5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Flagging to delete my answer - this works a thousand times better, and actually is elegant (especially in comparison).  +1

Comment: What if its a 2 digit number?

Comment: You will get text running outside the image. My guess is that it probably will only be used for small lists, but I could be wrong. If it is the case that they need to be double digits then they will have to play with the size of the text and or the size of the background image.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. list-style-position is my new friend :) I'm using this for a short list, but I'm not sure how to handle two+ digit numbers... I also edited the answer some to include some text indenting so the li text aligns properly if it runs onto multiple lines. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer in following way

```
 /* reset the ol counter with class liststyled*/
ol.liststyled {
counter-reset: item;
list-style-type: none;
list-style-position: inside;
padding-left: 0;
}
/* make the li relative */
ol.liststyled li{
position: relative;   
padding-left: 35px;
}
/*add absolute positioned img element background to our relative li */
ol.liststyled li:before{
font-size: .8em;
line-height: 25px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 25px;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
height: 25px;
content: counter(item) "  "; 
counter-increment: item ;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: url('../img/bulletolback.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems the best way to me.... [Customize Ordered Lists with the ::before Pseudo- Element](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/customize-ordered-lists-pseudo-element)

Answer (score 0):

Use `list-style-image` css rule with the url for the image.  Here is an example from [the Mozilla documentation for CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-image),

```
ul { 
    list-style-image: url("images/arrow.gif") 
}
```

You can also check out their [live demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/list-style).

Oh wait, I just realized that that won't let you have the numbers in the images...ok, well this at least gets you partially the way there...

Comment: That removes the number all together in my test (in Chrome)

Comment: @ETWW yeah, I just realized that :/

Comment: Leaving this answer because it's good to know that this won't quite solve the problem this way.